# Linq left outer join with exclusion via Linq2db

Tags: vb.net, linq, ms-access, linq2db

Using `Linq2db` and `Ms Access` I want to select all sectors that don't have targets ergo I want to execute left outer join with exclusion:

```
Dim q10 = From s In db.Sectors
          From t In db.Targets.Where(Function(f) f.id_sector = s.Id).DefaultIfEmpty
          Where t Is Nothing
          Select s
```

`Linq2db` resolves this as:

```
--  Access
SELECT
    [t2].[Id],
    [t2].[Name]
FROM
    [tblSector] [t2]
        LEFT JOIN [tblTarget] [t1] ON ([t1].[id_sector] = [t2].[Id])
WHERE
    [t1].* IS NULL <=========== HERE
```

which obviously is wrong.

I tried also:

```
Dim q10 = From s In db.Sectors
          From t In db.Targets.Where(Function(f) f.id_sector = s.Id And f Is Nothing).DefaultIfEmpty
          Select s
```

receiving:

```
--  Access
SELECT
    [t2].[Id],
    [t2].[Name]
FROM
    [tblSector] [t2]
        LEFT JOIN [tblTarget] [t1] ON ([t1].[id_sector] = [t2].[Id] AND [t1].* IS NULL) <=========== HERE
```

Summarize, I need:

```
SELECT
    [t2].[Id],
    [t2].[Name]
FROM
    [tblSector] [t2]
        LEFT JOIN [tblTarget] [t1] ON ([t1].[id_sector] = [t2].[Id])
WHERE
    [t1].[id_sector] IS NULL
```

How to write in condition `Where t1.id_sector Is Nothing` (id_sector is `FK` so it is `Integer` so it can't be `Nothing`.

Comment: Perhaps you really need RIGHT JOIN. Whatever it's called, you probably need "All records from Sector and only those from Target that match".

Comment: I am not sure what is the difference between the first option and the option you need - if `id_sector` is null then the entire raw is null, so there is no actual difference between the two queries

Comment: @gilmishal Exactly. No difference. The problem is that `Linq2db` can't resolve proper linq query to SQL query. So my question is how to write linq query in `linq2db` to achieve result as in last SQL example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. It's a little workaround but it works.

Because this query doesn't work in `linq2db`:

```
Dim q10 = From s In db.Sectors
          From t In db.Targets.Where(Function(f) f.id_sector = s.Id).DefaultIfEmpty
          Where t Is Nothing
          Select s
```

Instead we can write like this:

```
Dim q10 = From s In db.Sectors 
          Where Not (From t In db.Targets Select t.id_sector).Contains(s.Id)
          Select s
```

However generated SQL instead looking like this:

```
SELECT
    [t2].[Id],
    [t2].[Name]
FROM
    [tblSector] [t2]
        LEFT JOIN [tblTarget] [t1] ON ([t1].[id_sector] = [t2].[Id])
WHERE
    [t1].[id_sector] IS NULL
```

It looks like this:

```
SELECT
    [t2].[Id],
    [t2].[Name]
FROM
    [tblSector] [t2]
WHERE
    NOT (EXISTS(
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            [tblTarget] [t1]
        WHERE
            [t1].[id_sector] = [t2].[Id]
    ))
```

Comment: I don't use VB.Net, but in c# I can achieve a similar result by simply checking if `t.id_sector == (int?)null`. In other words, casting null as a nullable integer (casting the field also works). The IDE will complain this this is a redundant cast, but linq2db will correctly generate a SQL expression that checks for a null value based on this cast.